# Excel find last record of specified value in range

Tags: excel, range, record

I have a excel formula question.
I have table/range of some accounts activity during days with amounts as bellow

```
date / account / amount  
1-Jan / 20 / 60  
1-Jan / 30 / 2  
2-Jan / 20 / 3  
2-Jan / 20 / 4  
3-Jan / 10 / 5  
4-Jan / 20 / 6
```

I want to extract last record of given accounts as bellow

```
10 -> 3-jan / 5
30 -> 1-Jan / 2
```

which formulas will find last in range based on criteria?
How Can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2016 from a 365 license, you can use the new MAXIF. In previous versions, use an array formula like this in F2 in the screenshot:

=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$7=E2,$A$2:$A$7))

Note that it must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>, otherwise it will not work.

Then look up the amount with this formula in G2 in the screenshot.

=INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(F2&E2,INDEX($A$2:$A$7&$B$2:$B$7,0),))

Copy both formulas down

[image]

Comment: Dear teylyn, it works well, I learned a new Technique also .Many Thanks

Comment: What if date column not be in Date type and be in string/Text? it gets N/A? want last item, MAX not works on text type.  any replace for MAX?

Comment: It is impossible to get the latest date from a text string. Convert text to real dates.